# I have seen people using return -1 at the end of function. What does it actually mean?

Tags: java, stack

I am implementing stack in java. While doing this I saw a code where a function returns -1. Like this one:

```
public int peek()
    {
        if (!isEmpty())
            return arr[top];
        else
            System.exit(1);

        return -1;
    }
```

What does it actually mean returning a -1 value?

Comment: that -1 will never be returned

Comment: What does it mean actually?

Comment: It means that if this line were reached, a `-1` would be returned. To make a statement about the semantics, we would have to see more code. If I were to guess, I would say that it is either some value to satisfy the compiler or was meant as a flag-/error-code value to signal that the operation could not be executed. An in my opinion cleaner solution would be to throw an `Exception` (e.g. `IllegalStateException`), hence referring the handling of this situation to the calling side.

Comment: _Why_ is there a `System.exit` call inside a `peek` method???

Comment: It's a terrible example. The whole JVM is stopped if the collection is empty. In this case -1 has no meaning, as it will never be returned. It's only there because the compiler will complain that the method must return a value in all cases.

Comment: So the return value could be anything @RealSkeptic

Answer (score 3):

```
System.exit(1);
```

Ends the JVM and returns the exit status 1 to the OS.

You know, `return -1;` will never be executed, but the compiler has to enforce, that EVERY method, that says in the signature, that it returns something, has either a return-statement or a throw at every end of the control flow.